# Why does function from trimr package remove all data?

Tags: r, statistics, outliers

I am removing outliers from my data using a non-recursive method as described by Van Selst & Jolicoeur (1994). To do this I've been using the `trimr` package to remove outliers at the participant and condition level and return the raw data with these removed.

However, the result is *all* data is removed, not just the outliers, and I can't figure out why.

Here is a dummy of my data:

```
df <- data.frame(participant = c(rep(1, times = 3), rep(2, times = 3)),
                 condition = rep(c("control", "AOMIspec", "AOMIgen"), times = 2),
                 word = rep(c("ascend", "frugal", "campus"), times = 2),
                 accuracyScore = rep(NA, times = 6),
                 wholeWordTime = c(1.721456, 1.772691, 1.618516, 2.0550096, 2.1921245, 3.0659085)
)

  participant condition   word accuracyScore wholeWordTime
1           1   control ascend            NA      1.721456
2           1  AOMIspec frugal            NA      1.772691
3           1   AOMIgen campus            NA      1.618516
4           2   control ascend            NA      2.055010
5           2  AOMIspec frugal            NA      2.192124
6           2   AOMIgen campus            NA      3.065908
```

And here is the code to remove outliers:

```
library(trimr)
df_trim <- trimr::nonRecursive(data = df, minRT = 0.1, pptVar = "participant",
                                  condVar = "condition", rtVar = "wholeWordTime", 
                                  accVar = "accuracyScore", digits = 5, 
                                  returnType = "raw", omitErrors = FALSE)
```

I have used this same function in exactly the same way for other data and it's worked perfectly, so I'm guessing the issue is somewhere in the data itself.

Also, yes, I know the `accuracyScore` column is full of NAs, but it's supposed to be, and I have used the same function on other data with NAs in this column and it worked fine, so this doesn't seem to be the issue.

I also don't get any errors - the function seems to work fine, but just removes every observation from the dataset.

Any ideas hugely appreciated as I'm quite stuck on this one.

Comment: With only one value for each combination of participant and condition it can't calculate a SD to use for trimming

Comment: @Miff thanks for the comment! Well spotted, so this makes my dummy example now work and data is returned by the trimr function, but my real dataset has 30 observations in each condition and for some reason still returns 0 rows using this code, so sadly doesn't help me there.

Comment: Okie dokie, figured it out and feel silly. My dataset had NAs in the 'wholeWordTime' column which was causing the issue! Apologies because I appreciate no one could solve this from the example I gave either!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My dataset had NAs in the 'wholeWordTime' column which was causing the issue! Apologies because I appreciate no one could solve this from the example I gave either!

Answer (score 1):

author of the package here. I'm not sure at first glance what is causing this error, but I note that with more data per participant in your example data it returns all the data. (Still not the behaviour you're after, but it might help locate what's going on.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  participant = c(rep(1, times = 30), rep(2, times = 30)), 
  condition = rep(c("control", "AOMIspec", "AOMIgen"), times = 20), 
  word = rep(c("ascend", "frugal", "campus"), times = 20), 
  accuracyScore = rep(NA, times = 60), 
  wholeWordTime = rnorm(60, 1.5, 0.4)
)

df_trim <- trimr::nonRecursive(data = df, minRT = 0.1, pptVar = "participant",
                               condVar = "condition", rtVar = "wholeWordTime", 
                               accVar = "accuracyScore", digits = 1, 
                               returnType = "raw", omitErrors = FALSE)
```

Also, with this larger data set I also note that if you ask for the "returnType" to be "mean" it also doesn't return what you might expect.

All of this may point to a bug in this nonRecursive function. If could confirm whether you can (or not!) reproduce the above with your own setup that might confirm there's something up.

If so, can you please log an issue on the package's GitHub page: [Hi - author of the package here. I'm not sure at first glance what is causing this error, but I note that with more data per participant in your example data it returns all the data. (Still not the behaviour you're after, but it might help locate what's going on.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  participant = c(rep(1, times = 30), rep(2, times = 30)), 
  condition = rep(c("control", "AOMIspec", "AOMIgen"), times = 20), 
  word = rep(c("ascend", "frugal", "campus"), times = 20), 
  accuracyScore = rep(NA, times = 60), 
  wholeWordTime = rnorm(60, 1.5, 0.4)
)

df_trim <- trimr::nonRecursive(data = df, minRT = 0.1, pptVar = "participant",
                               condVar = "condition", rtVar = "wholeWordTime", 
                               accVar = "accuracyScore", digits = 1, 
                               returnType = "raw", omitErrors = FALSE)
```

Also, with this larger data set I also note that if you ask for the "returnType" to be "mean" it also doesn't return what you might expect.

All of this may point to a bug in this nonRecursive function. If could confirm whether you can (or not!) reproduce the above with your own setup that might confirm there's something up.

If so, can you please log an issue on the trimr GitHub page: https://github.com/JimGrange/trimr/issues